# Two arrayCollection. Only one is an ArrayCollection

Tags: arrays, symfony

I have an Entity with two CollectionType but when I dump this entity I just have one with the ArrayCollection.

[image]

[image]

In my orderproductType I put this code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dimension')
        ->add('product', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ProductType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
        ))
        ->add('machining', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => MachiningType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

And in my entity :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="Orderproduct")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductBundle\Entity\Machining", mappedBy="Orderproduct")
 */
private $machining;
```

- add / remove and get.

Any idea ?

Thx

Comment: In the entity constructor, you assign both attributes a `new ArrayCollection`? Also, why is this important - does it break your code?

Comment: @kero I've got this error `A new entity was found through the relationship 'ProductBundle\Entity\Orderproduct#product' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: `

Comment: Or it's simply my relation ? Need to change for ManyToOne in product and Machining ?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with array or ArrayCollection. See [answers like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215975/doctrine-a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relationship)

Comment: Thx for your help !