# Doctrine ORM "Multiple non-persisted new entities were found through the given association graph:"

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

```
$added_obj = []; 
foreach ($something as $data) {
    $obj = $this->class->function($data, $par2);

    if (null !== $obj && !(array_key_exists
    (->getVal1(), $added_obj[$obj->getVal1()] === $$obj->getVal2())) {
        $this->persister->persist($obj);
        $added_bank_account[$obj->getVal1()] = $obj->getVal2();
    } else {

    }
}
```

What the code does: It calls an function which returns an entity or null. If an entity was created there is an check if 2 values already exists in an array, if not, than persist and add the 2 values to an array as key/val pair.

But, when an entity is created and it already exists in the array i don't want it to be persisted, but I want to do nothing with it.

But, when I do absolutely zero with it I got the error: 
```Multiple non-persisted new entities were found through the given association graph:

- A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyCompany\Client\Entity\Client#something' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:

which makes sense because doctrine doesn't know what to do with the created entity. How can I "destroy" the created entity so that the problem is solved.

When there is only 1 object created everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply `merge` or `clear` the `entity` from `EntityManager`

ex :

```
$em->merge($obj);
```

OR

```
$em->clear($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because it was trying to insert a duplicated registry in a particular table, when in fact I was just trying to update it.

I was doing a `persist` **with** a `flush` right after.

So I found that (obvious for many, but certainly helpful):

**->merge** 
will duplicate the registry in many cases, if the id is not set properly.
If you are trying to update an entity, this is not a good idea.

**->persist**
In the same way, if you are trying to update an entity, you may not use it. It's used to add a new entity to the db. To update a record, you may just use `flush` as you can see in [this example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object) from the docs.

Comment: merge function is depreciated now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and googling this error did not give me much results, but it appeared that in case of only one entity (not multiple) doctrine gives different error message, which has a solution that worked for multiple entities too. So, let me leave here a link for it: [Doctrine - A new entity was found through the relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215975/doctrine-a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if you got the related entity in another object manager. For example, if there was previously a check for duplication through an exception and resetting the manager.