# Symfony 4 relation many-to-one and cascade persit

Tags: symfony, many-to-one

I have a problem with a many to one relationship.

Here I have a Client entity that already exists. Then I try to link Documents to this entity.

I have a document creation form with a selector that lists my clients. There are no problems.

But when I try to record my dcoument I have the following message:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Document#Client' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\Client@000000006889f4d900000000795bd53c. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\Client#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

I do not understand why I must persit my client entity.

In my document entity I have this:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", inversedBy="Documents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Client;
```

And in my Client entity I have this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", mappedBy="Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Documents;
```

Do you have any idea about the nature of my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine - A new entity was found through the relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215975/doctrine-a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", inversedBy="Documents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Client;
```

to

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", inversedBy="Documents", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Client;
```

Comment: now i have this error : Notice: Undefined index: 0000000021c853f2000000000f9ea414

Comment: @wehtam Please, provide more details (like exception stack trace).

Comment: ErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: 000000003d39d146000000006d27e6db

at vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php:2997 at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->getEntityIdentifier(object(ModePaiement)) (vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php:677) at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->prepareUpdateData(object(Client)) (vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php:713) at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->prepareInsertData(object(Client))