# Weird problems when handling large amounts of entities

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have a command that is creating / updating large amounts of products for a webshop (90,000 products or so).

After it has gone through about 1000 - 1500 products or so it gives the following error when trying to persist just about anything:

**'Failed to open stream: Too many open files'**

I do a flush every 50 products, i have tried calling em->clear() while doing this flush, however this just results in persist errors like:

**A new entity was found through the relationship: ...** on just about every entity after the clear.

Does anyone know a fix for this issue? I can't think of anything anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We cannot help debug a story, we can help debug some code

Comment: Can you break up the updates into separate batches?

Comment: SHow us how you are using FILES in this process please

Comment: This related answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556435/10664489